# Recurrence relations Discrete Math

Tags: sequences-and-series

Instructions say: Find the solution to the recurrence relation and prove the correctness of your solution using mathematical induction.

$$
a_{n} = a_{n - 1} + 3\,,\quad n \geq 1\,;\qquad a_{0} = 1
$$

Please help I am completely confused, I've read the textbook section on mathematical induction and I'm so confused please be as descriptive in your explanations as possible.

Comment: please verify the formatting

Comment: it is a sub n is equal to, a sub n minus one, plus three. and a sub 0 is equal to 1. The formatting in my original post looks just like the problem.

Answer (score 1):

As $\displaystyle a_n-a_{n-1}=3$ which is independent of $n$

it is an Arithmetic Series with common difference $=3$

So, $\displaystyle a_n=a_0+n\cdot3$

For the inductive proof, let $\displaystyle a_n=a_0+n\cdot3$ holds true for $n=m$

i.e., $\displaystyle a_m=a_0+m\cdot3$

$\displaystyle\implies a_{m+1}=a_m+3=\cdots$

Comment: I appreciate your help a lot. I understand a little, the proofs for these problems seem arbitrary to me. I just don't get it.

Comment: @user130722, can you please pinpoint the confusion. DO you know about inductive proof, in general?

Comment: Kind of, we have to form a basis to show the given statement is true: $a_0 = 1$. I don't understand how that's true. $a_0$ in that expression would be $a_{0-1} + 3$, how do we know what $a_{-1}$ is? I'm guessing zero, which would then leave us with $a_0 = 3$, but it isn't!? \n After we show the basis to be true we need to prove that the original equation is true for any random integer m + 1.

Comment: @user130722, haven't you noticed $$n\ge1$$ in your Question itself?

Comment: The original problem did not state that $ n\ge1$. Maybe we are just supposed to assume and know that?

Comment: But do you understand that the recursion tells you to start with 1 and count up in steps of 3, producing the sequence 1,4,7,10,13,...?